# Samsung S4 Update has completely disfigured phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova, samsung-mobile

I'm currently developing my final year project, which is due this month, using phonegap and the most recent update to the Samsung Galaxy S4 seems to have completely disfigured everything in my application.
Has anyone come across this issue before or have any idea how to fix this ASAP?
Thanks lots,
Paula

Comment: The newest update is KitKat, I guess, which introduced the new Chromium-based web views. This migration guide might help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this when using phonegap and sencha touch. First thing to do is make sure you update your app to the current version of phonegap. Typically they will release new version along side of android.

If your still getting the issues after the phonegap update. I would suggest looking into what browser it is using. Several phone manufacturers put their own flavor into the web browser which can affect your code. I previously had an issue with htc do to the browser handling css differently. Android APIs are the same, some will use different browser code so you will have to test it against each to make sure it works.

I also believe phonegap allows you to modify what browser it uses. It may default to chromium now but in the past you could switch it depending on what api version it was.